# Android Studio: Task 'testClasses' not found in project

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, robolectric

I finally have a Test Case setup for Roboelectric but when I try to run it from Android Studio,  get this error:
Task 'testClasses' not found in project 'myExternalProjectName'

Error:Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\Mike.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53\gradle-2.2.1'.

NOTES: 
1. When I run from gradle cmd line(gradlew build) the tests run fine
2. I'M USING : org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0

I have modules in my project as AARs. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: anyone have an idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132996/android-skip-gradle-testclasses-task-for-a-dependency-project worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

To bypass the error, please add below code in build.gradle

```
task("testClasses")
```

This error happens when I rebuild the project and this is from Kotlin Multiplatform plugin/library. Still don't know the actual error cause.

EDIT: The `task("testClasses")` line should go in the shared module's `build.gradle.kts` file, within the `kotlin { }` block.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this error after setting up signing configs. `File` -> `invalidate caches` -> `invalidate and restart` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: WFM when I got this error after upgrading the KMM plugin.

Comment: Ah interesting, I was setting up a KMM project. Wasn't sure if related but it sounds like it might be.

Comment: This also happened to me in my shared module, I ran `./gradlew clean`, synced, and rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all test configuration first and then run your test from test package.

Steps:

- step 1.- Go to Run/Debug configuration
- step 2.- Remove All test configuration file with selecting config and press (-)
- step 3.- Press Apply and OK
- step 4.- Run the test again

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've been there! When facing the 'testClasses' hiccup in Android Studio with Robolectric, it's often a Gradle-related snag. Have you tried syncing Gradle files in Android Studio? Sometimes, a good sync does the trick. Also, ensure your Robolectric version aligns with your Gradle settings. If all else fails, a clean and rebuild could save the day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my comment will be useful, but I've solved that problem with those steps:

1. Comment "include ':app'" into the setting.gradle.
2. Try to rebuild. (it'll fail)
3. Uncomment "include ':app'" into the setting.gradle.
4. Try to rebuild. Done