# KMM project build error - 'testClasses' not found in project ':shared'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying out KMM for the first time and when I try to rebuild the project, I get this error. Not sure what this task does. Am I the only one getting this error?

I'm using a Macbook Pro M1 that runs

Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

```
Executing tasks: [:androidApp:clean, :shared:clean, 
:androidApp:assembleDebug, :androidApp:assembleDebugUnitTest, 
:androidApp:assembleDebugAndroidTest, :shared:assembleDebug, 
:shared:assembleDebugUnitTest, :shared:assembleDebugAndroidTest, 
:shared:assemble, :shared:testClasses] in project 
/Users/betteropinions/Development/KMM/TranslateKMMApp

Calculating task graph as no configuration cache is available for 
tasks: :androidApp:clean :shared:clean :androidApp:assembleDebug 
:androidApp:assembleDebugUnitTest 
:androidApp:assembleDebugAndroidTest :shared:assembleDebug 
:shared:assembleDebugUnitTest :shared:assembleDebugAndroidTest 
:shared:assemble :shared:testClasses
Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Cannot locate tasks that match ':shared:testClasses' as task 
'testClasses' not found in project ':shared'.

* Try: 
> Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> For more on name expansion, please refer to 
https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/
command_line_interface.html#sec: 
name_abbreviation in the Gradle documentation.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Configuration cache entry stored.
```

Below is the build.gradle.kts for shared module

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinSerialization)
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }

    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "16.0"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {

        commonMain.dependencies {
            //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
            implementation(libs.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json)
            implementation(libs.sqldelight.coroutines.extensions)
            implementation(libs.sqldelight.runtime)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
        }

        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test"))
            implementation(libs.turbine)
            implementation(libs.assertk)
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
            implementation(libs.sqldelight.android.driver)
        }

        iosMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
            implementation(libs.sqldelight.native.driver)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mytranslate"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

sqldelight {
    database("TranslateDatabase") {
        packageName = "com.example.mytranslate.database"
        sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the build.gradle file belonging to the shared module. thank you

Comment: @Lino, I have modified the question by adding the build.gradle of the shared module. This issue comes only when I click on the rebuild option.

Comment: I am experimenting the same issue, looks like a bug when adding CMP to an already existing project, however, on a CMP imported via Jetbrains wizard, works fine

Comment: @JaviMar I am still getting this error when using the jetbrains wizard (https://kmp.jetbrains.com/) without altering any of the code provided by it or adding anything to it. Does this still work for you?

Comment: @C.Toni After adding the below-given task in the build.gradle.kts file, my KMP project builds successfully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/78017056/6512100 works for me.

I've added `task("testClasses")` within.in `kotlin { }` block in `build.gradle.kts (:shared)` file.

```
plugins {
    ...
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        ...
    }

    sourceSets {
        ...
    }

    task("testClasses")
}

android {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is working. Accepting your answer. Thank you :)